# SSH with Apache giving no /dev/tty error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssh, tomcat

I'm trying to exec a command to ssh into a host from a Tomcat instance that runs as Apache. 
This isn't working because of the following error:

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

However, if I open a shell and manually `su` to the apache user, I can execute this command just fine.

Do I need to change configuration or can I possibly use the `-t` option with ssh to specify a device or address that exists?

Comment: Were you prompted for a password when you run the ssh as apache user?

Comment: @khaled no I use  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no , and that log entry is taken from using -v. The reason ssh is failing is because when Tomcat runs that command as Apache, there is no /dev/tty device. Apparently for the Tomcat process /dev/tty is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1094856.html) says that this error may happen if the ssh requires some input. [Another link](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Can%27t_open_/dev/tty:_No_such_device_or_address_Error_%28Linux%29) says that you should create a missing `/dev/tty` file. A [third link](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.security.ssh/browse_thread/thread/fdf5fa7bd1161b36) says that should find a way to tell you daemon to not open this file.

Comment: I'd like to try what's mentioned in the third link, but I haven't found any good explanation on the web.